# How to deserialize Json responses from http requests in a loop

Tags: c++, json, arduino, deserialization

I am using an [Adafruit Feather Huzzah ESP8266](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-huzzah-esp8266/overview) and the [ArduinoJson library](https://arduinojson.org) to parse the response of an HTTP request. I am successfully getting the expected responses but the deserialization process fails *every other time* it iterates through the loop. I think it may be a memory allocation issue but I cannot resolve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using dynamic vs static documents and initialising them inside/outside the loop without success. I have also tried the doc.clear() method to release the memory but still no luck. Below is my loop with the connection parameters missing:

```
void loop() {
  WiFiClientSecure client;

  for (int i = 0; i <= numOfInstallations - 1; i++) {

    String url = "/v2/installations/" + String(idSites[i]) + 
               "/widgets/Graph?attributeCodes[]=SOC&instance=" + String(instance[i]) + 
               "&start=" + String(startTime) + 
               "&end=" + String(endTime);

    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "X-Authorization: Token " + token + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");

    Serial.println(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
             "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
             "X-Authorization: Token " + token + "\r\n" +
             "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");

    Serial.println("request sent");
    delay(500);

    // Ignore the response headers
    char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
    if (!client.find(endOfHeaders)) {
      Serial.println(F("No headers"));
      return;
    }
    const size_t capacity = 5*JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(5) + 2*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 2*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(4) + 130;
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);                       // Json document setup
    // Get the Json data from the response
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, client);
    if (error) {
      Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
      Serial.println(error.c_str());
      Serial.print("\r\n");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("deserializeJson() successful\r\n");
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting the deserialization process to be successful each time but here is the output:

```
GET /v2/installations/xxxxx/widgets/Graph?attributeCodes[]=SOC&instance=215&start=1555070100&end=1555070400 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrmapi.victronenergy.com
X-Authorization: Token c324f8876e672ad1797cd69a9d9f62611507d25aa5a0b1ff40f9fb524d96f2fc
Connection: keep-alive


request sent
deserializeJson() successful

GET /v2/installations/xxxxx/widgets/Graph?attributeCodes[]=SOC&instance=258&start=1555070100&end=1555070400 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrmapi.victronenergy.com
X-Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXX
Connection: keep-alive


request sent
deserializeJson() failed: InvalidInput

GET /v2/installations/xxxxx/widgets/Graph?attributeCodes[]=SOC&instance=258&start=1555070100&end=1555070400 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrmapi.victronenergy.com
X-Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXX
Connection: keep-alive


request sent
deserializeJson() successful

GET /v2/installations/xxxxx/widgets/Graph?attributeCodes[]=SOC&instance=258&start=1555070100&end=1555070400 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrmapi.victronenergy.com
X-Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXX
Connection: keep-alive


request sent
deserializeJson() failed: InvalidInput

GET /v2/installations/xxxxx/widgets/Graph?attributeCodes[]=SOC&instance=258&start=1555070100&end=1555070400 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrmapi.victronenergy.com
X-Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXX
Connection: keep-alive


request sent
deserializeJson() successful
```

Comment: [OT]: you might replace `i <= numOfInstallations - 1` by `i < numOfInstallations`

Comment: Are you sure that response only have JSon, and no extra text to skip for next request?

Comment: Is there an "\r\n\r\n" left after the initial JSON, such that the second iteration tries to deserialise it's headers, the iteration after that the second iterations JSON, etc?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! There was still some characters in the receive buffer after the JSON. I used   

while(client.available()){
    client.read();
  }

after each iteration to fix it. If you have a better way of flushing the receive buffer, please let me know.